# RoR how to find a record backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 3 table - users, employees, contacts.
The employees and contacts have a foreign key pointing the the associated user.
Employee belongs_to :user
Contact belongs_to :user
User has many employees, contacts

But, I would like to list the employee name or contact name in the user index view.

Do I need to use a find_by_sql statement?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `belongs_to` associations set up already, so you can add the `has_one` association in your User class for employee and contact, then you can do `@user.employee.name` or `@user.contact.name`.

You definitely don't need `find_by_sql` for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your index view,

```
<table>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
  <td><%= user.employees.map{ |empl| empl.name }.join(", ") %></td>
  <td><%= user.contacts.map{ |contact| contact.name }.join(", ") %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The only down side is it will do a query for all the user's employees and all the user's contacts in the loop for user.  If the page loads reasonably fast, code it as above, because that's clearer code.